# java do while termination

Tags: java, validation, do-while

This program asks the user to input a number and then brings back the details from an list. how do I do this?

```
         do {
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);             
            System.out.println("Enter Number <terminated by 1>");

             }  while (!input.equals("-1"));
                System.out.println("Session Over");

        } catch (Exception e) {   
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Enter Number <terminated by 1>
123456
Person Number: 12
```

Comment: Not that it solves anything but you shouldn't create many instances of Scanner which will handle `System.in`. So move line creating it before your `do{..}` loop.

Comment: Call `e.printStacktrace()` to know which instruction throws the Exception.

Comment: is not your real code. It is not compiling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

`while (input != -1);` would be the right way to compare two integer values.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can't test variables in do-while loop when variable is inside loop:

```
do {
    int i = 10;
} while (i > 5);
```

will not compile.

Also, `int input;` doesn't have `equals` method as `int` type is primitive.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the Scanner initialization from the loop and put it in the try block, as Pshemo pointed out.

```
try {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    yada yada yada
}
```

Then try wrapping your negation in your while loop as in:

```
while (!(input.equals("-1")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pro Tip: use an IDE.

Your code is incorrect for at least two reasons:

1. your `int input` is defined inside the `do` block, so it is not visible after it closes
2. you use `.equals` on a primitive type

Correct your code as follows:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Client c = new Client();
        c.run();
    }

    private void run() {
        StudentData p = new StudentData();
        List<StudentDetailsType> personDetailsList = (List<StudentDetailsType>) p.getList();


        // input defined outside the do block so it is visible in while clause
        int input;
        // declare the scanner just one time here, so it will be closed automatically as the try/catch block ends
        try(Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter 6 digit Student Number <terminated by -1>");
                input = in.nextInt();
                for (StudentDetailsType q : personDetailsList) {

                    if (q.getStudentNumber() == input) {
                        System.out.println("Student Number: " + q.getStudentNumber() + "\n" + "Student Name: "
                                + q.getStudentName() + "\n" + "Result 1: " + q.getResult1() + "\n" + "Result 2: "
                                + q.getResult2() + "\n" + "Result 3: " + q.getResult3());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } while (input != -1); // use an int comparison (!= that means not equals)

            System.out.println("Session Over");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```